# Loading screen for GoogleMaps activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to implement a loading screen since `GoogleMaps` sometimes takes ~2 seconds to load. I tried using a `RelativeLayout` and putting the `ImageView` above the map `fragment` and making it `ViewStates.Gone` once the map loads. However, I noticed that the loading is happening on `base.OnCreateBundle` and not on `SetUpMap()` and now I'm clueless how to implement it.

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Map);
    mSplash = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.splash);
    SetUpMap();
}

private void SetUpMap()
{
    if (mMap == null)
    {
        FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment(Resource.Id.map).GetMapAsync(this);
    }
}

public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mSplash.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeSatellite;
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, OnMapReady is meant to be used to verify that Google Play Services is installed and active on the device. As the documentation puts it:

> If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will
>   be prompted to install it, and the onMapReady(GoogleMap) method will
>   only be triggered when the user has installed it and returned to the
>   app.

[OnMapReady Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback)

Alternatively, the OnMapLoaded function is meant to be called after the map has finished loading its tiles.

> Called when the map has finished rendering. This will only be called
>   once. You must request another callback if you want to be notified
>   again.

[OnMapLoaded Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback)

You can implement the OnMapLoaded function by first setting the callback once you have a reference to the map

```
 mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
```

Finish by simply overriding the OnMapLoaded function and handling it accordingly

```
@Override
public void onMapLoaded() {
    if (mMap != null) {
        mSplash.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    }
}
```

Remember that if you need to load the map again and need to display another splash screen, you will first need to set the callback again, as onMapLoaded is only called once per callback.

Comment: It works but the loading image stays visible for a very short time, because there are a lot of things happening on `OnCreate` and the screen in black at the time - then a short view of the loading image - then the map shows